# Running PhantomJS as daemon in OS X

Tags: php, javascript, permissions, command-line-interface, phantomjs

I am using Zend framework and [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to render images for a site I work on. I have a job listener script that loops and looks for jobs in a queue.  Upon finding a job, it uses data from the job message to construct a phantomJS command and executes the command via 
php's EXEC command.

This process works great if I start the job listener myself from the command line.  However if the daemon user (web user in OS X)   attempts to run phantomJS, nothing happens.  No error message, nothing.

I have tried several things including
 1. *adding this line to sudoers  daemon ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/phantomjs*
 2. *giving phantomjs and its parent directory 777 permissions.*
 3. *giving daemon ownership of phantomjs*

However, despite all of this, I cannot get execute phantomJS from Daemon user.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or add some suggestions,  I would be very appreciative.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: Tried running phantomjs with `--debug=yes`? Also, did you try running it as the daemon user with sudo from the CLI? `sudo -u daemon phantomjs --debug=yes ...`. Might be an environment issue (NODE_PATH?).

Answer (score 2):

You could try run your phantomjs script like a service instead of run it by EXEC command.

> Using an embedded web server module called Mongoose, PhantomJS script can start a web  server. This is intended for ease of communication between PhantomJS scripts and the outside world and is not recommended for use as a general production server.

For information about how works the embedded web server see [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/)

Here an example about how a PhantomJS script can start a web server.

```js
var server = require('webserver').create();
var service = server.listen('127.0.0.1:8080', function(request, response) {
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.write('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');
    response.close();
});
```

After the services is running, it can send as response a JSON Object which can be easily interpreted by PHP.

To listen to ANY domain `server.listen('8080', ....)`

set HTTP response headers `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");`